# Вывод своего столбца в SQL Server

Tags: запрос, база-данных, sql-server, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в SQL можно вывести столбик, включающий в себя заданное количество строк со своим текстом (текст должен быть статическим). 
Поясню, необходимо чтобы слева от столбца (см. скриншот) появился ещё один столбец в котором были 4 строчки с пояснениями к  каждой цифре:

[image]

Заранее благодарен!

**UPD:**
Надо что-то наподобие как на скрине ниже, только текст в каждой строчке свой.
Тут вывел просто через (SELECT 'Один'), но таким способом не получается вывести более 1 разного текста, т.е. (SELECT ('Один', 'Два', 'Три', 'Четыре')) не работает

[image]

**UPD 2:**
Вот, то, что должно получиться на выходе - нарисовал в пейнте. Проблема в том, что первый столбец надо сделать на SQL. Текст Один, Два, Три, Четыре должен быть в самом запросе.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых объясните по-человечески как у вас устроена таблица, желательно в виде SQL.
Во-вторых объясните чего вы в конечном итоге хотите добиться, что бы из этой таблицы 
просто выбирались две строки, это просто:

```
SELECT column1, clomun2 FROM table LIMIT n;
```

Если вы хотите, что бы у вас значения выбирались из разных таблиц, в этом тоже нет ничего сложного:

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column1 FROM table1, table2
```

И наконец, если вы хотите просто дописать несколько слов на вывод, зачем тут лепить SQL я не знаю.

Comment: Проблема в том, что этого текста из первой колонки второго скриншота нету в БД. Этот текст должен быть в самом запросе

Comment: Вот, то, что должно получиться на выходе - нарисовал в пейнте. Проблема в том, что первый столбец надо сделать на SQL
http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4551/kzsn.png

Comment: Зачем так извращаться над SQL, создайте таблицу или колонку и не усложняйте себе жизнь.

Comment: У меня нет прав на запись в БД. А вывести текст надо именно запросом, т.к. потом этот запрос в хранимой процедуре будет подхватывать другая программа и выводить.
Поэтому и приходится извращаться

Answer (score 1):

```
select ... , 'какой-то свой статический текст'
from ...
```

upd.
зависит от версии SQL Server 
в 2000 я бы 1 селектом не обошелся. (использовал бы промежуточную переменную типа table с автоинкриментом, вставил бы туда данные в нужном порядке, затем уже вывел)...
в 2005 наверно [так](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133/ru)

Comment: @AlexG212 Посмотрите второй скриншот и пояснение к нему

Comment: ну как цифры получить вроде понятно.. 1,2,3,4. а из цифр сделать текст вроде не проблема: либо функцию написать, либо case

Answer (score 1):

От чего зависит текст, то и обрабатываете, например:

```
select case количество when 298 then 'Один' end Пояснение,количество 
from таблица
```

Comment: Но число из второй колонки может меняться, к нему нельзя привязываться:)
Лучше бы привязать слово к номеру строчки, но у меня что-то не вышло.

Comment: Это пример. К чему я еще должен был привязаться, если вы кроме одного столбца больше ничего не показали?
Хотите к номеру строчки - нет проблем, но тогда нужно бы указать как эти строчки сортируются. Видно, что не по вашему столбцу. Значит опять пролет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё поиграться с UNION ALL

```
SELECT 'НАЗВАНИЕ ПЕРВОЙ СТРОЧКИ' AS "НАЗВАНИЕ ПЕРВОГО ПОЛЯ",
   'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 1' as "НАЗВАНИЕ ВТОРОГО ПОЛЯ"
FROM ТАБЛИЦА
UNION ALL
SELECT 'НАЗВАНИЕ ВТОРОЙ СТРОЧКИ', 'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 2'
FROM ТАБЛИЦА
WHERE условие для удаления декартового произведение
```